# Brackets live preview takes time to refresh a page

Tags: windows-10, php, preview, refresh, brackets

I am using brackets to code a php website and live preview mapped to the htdocs/mysite folder. From the last 2 days, any update I do on the code is not reflecting immediately on the live preview and on the actual page. Is anyone here familiar with this problem?

Comment: its clearly cached, but where and how takes a bit of troubleshooting. first. use firefox, and clear its cache. Chrome often causes these issues via its obsessive focus on local caching, and IE occasionally caches content in ways it doesn't let you easily clear. if the problem persists in FF, then the issue is caching server-side, in which case you will need to focus on disabling or reconfiguring its caching.   don't know about your webserver, but with IIS .Net sites, new code is not compiled until the app pool is recycled or restarted, so thats somthing to consider.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying to help. I just realized that I had allsync installed on my local machine backing up my work to dropbox folder and for some reason, it stopped syncing. My brackets was mapped to the dropbox folder and I was working on my local machine desktop folder. It was silly me, didn't realize they were pointing to two folders at different locations and were not in Sync.